# Only index documents that contain a specific string in solr

Tags: solr, indexing

How to index documents that contain specific string in solr? This is my current dataimporthandler

```
<dataConfig>
        <dataSource type="FileDataSource" encoding="UTF-8" />
        <document>
        <entity name="page"
                processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
                stream="true"
                forEach="/mediawiki/page/"
                url="pages.xml"
                transformer="RegexTransformer"
                >
            <field column="id"        xpath="/mediawiki/page/id" />
            <field column="title"     xpath="/mediawiki/page/title" />
            <field column="text"   regex="\{\{PersonData"   xpath="/mediawiki/page/revision/text" />
       </entity>
        </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I only want to index if the text field contain {{PersonData , but the above imports everything . Should this be specified in import handler or schema?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
<field column="$skipDoc" regex="^#REDIRECT .*" replaceWith="true" sourceColName="text"/>
```

In this case documents matching the specified regex are skipped, ie. articles that are "redirects" to other articles are skipped here.

Detailed documentation here:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#XPathEntityProcessor

So for yours you need to find a way to say skip all documents where "PersonData" data is NOT in "text" column.

Look specifically at : "Example: Indexing wikipedia" part of http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#XPathEntityProcessor

Comment: @Naren Did you try above solution? It worked for me.